# Datagrid gone too wide, both online and local

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

Very odd. Today our datagrids extended too far to the right - with no code altered. I thought my hosting company may have done something, but it happened on local machine as well.

It's all very basic code

```
 <asp:DataGrid id="allUsersTable" runat="server"         
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gridstyle">
```

This was fitting perfectly for 10 years, then today it overflowed very oddly. Has Microsoft done an update?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmy9l.jpg

The red line is where the page usually ends. At the pink edge. But it's going too far, and causing a scroll bar. No code was touched, it just starting doing it on a number of pages! Any idea?

Comment: MS do updates ALL the time!!!

Comment: Maybe is a text that pushing the table...Please show us the code to help you better or replicate the code in the https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If I reduce the columns, it fits. But for the past decade, if I was on a small screen, it would simply make the columns narrower, and everything would fit. Never any side-scrolling.  Today my datagrids are a mess. I checked Twitter to see if it was a global issue, and I can't see any global outrage!

Comment: UPDATE - this seems to be only happening on Chrome. FF and IE work perfectly well. So it's a browser issue, not a MS issue. Hope that helps someone in the same boat.

Comment: @spankymac have you thought about setting the `Width` in your `css` file? It's possible that data that is populating the fields contain more data than usual? You can also use `ItemStyle` to set the columns width...

Comment: Yes, width is 100% in the CSS. I also set it in the datagrid itself. Actually, it seems to have fixed itself. 
Thanks for all your help!!